# Regression coefficient signs different for log/asinh and level versions of same variable

Tags: regression, logistic, econometrics, regression-coefficients

I ran two regressions. First, say, y=βx, and the second one, asinh(y)=βx, which I read is asymptotically equivalent to log(y)=βx, where x and y are the same variables with same data set for these two equations.

My confusion is that β is negative for the first regression (which I expected), but is positive for the second regression.

The sample size is the same for both regressions. Since I used asinh(y) instead of log(y), it did not drop zero values of y.

If it helps, I could totally regress in level-level mode, but the y variable is not normally distributed, and therefore, the asinh/log transformation.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the raw, un-transformed data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips, thanks for the comment, but I am sorry I do not have the authority to post a link of the data.

Comment: And is $asinh(y)$ normally distributed? Have you tried to plot the data in both cases? It might give you some insight. Spearman's correlation might also be helpful.

Comment: @Ertxiem you can be quite sure that the transformed data are not actually normally distributed. It's a model, not a fact about data.

Comment: @Samyam there's no assumption in regression about the unconditional distribution of Y. You may be trying to fix a non-existent problem. What sort of a variable is Y? (what does it measure? Is it a count? An amount of something?)

Comment: @Glen_b, y is income, which is obviously not normally distributed. ln(y) is normally distributed, and so is asinh(y). I am just finding it hard to realize why the sign is flipping when I use log or asinh transformation.

Comment: YourThe claim "ln(y) is normally distributed, and so is asinh(y)" is plainly false, since if one were actually normally distributed the other *couldn't possibly be normal*. However *none* of the three (Y, ln(Y), asinh(Y)) will actually be normally distributed. To repeat, normality of a population is a *model*. Real populations don't actually have normal distributions. If you have exact zeros, there is no transformation that can yield normality, so in this particular case non-normality of any of them is certain.

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks for the comment. Yes, there are certain observations with 0 value, but apart from that, the rest are normally distributed. Do you think it is problematic to use y that is not normally distributed as a dependent variable, especially with respect to the inference or for the correctness of the standard errors?

Comment: 1. "apart from that, the rest are normally distributed" -- on what do you base this claim? (You seem not to have understood some of my points, so it is necessary to deal with why you continue to think it's true.)  2.  As I mentioned in my first post, normality of the response itself (the population distribution of Y) is **not** an assumption of regression. The assumption relates to the conditional distribution (equivalently, to the distribution of the error term)

Comment: @Glen_b, the histogram shows that it is normally distributed? Minus some 0 values.

Comment: ["Normally distributed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is a model for a population (rather than a sample) and carries a very specific meaning. How would a histogram show that a variable has the pdf $f(x)= {\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^{2}}}}e^{-{\frac {(x-\mu )^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}}$? It might show something that looks more or less consistent with it, but some distributions with distinctly different properties from the normal can look quite close to normal, especially if all you have to go on is a small sample.